# Discrepancies between two SVD algorithms in scikit-learn: randomized vs APRACK

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, svd

I'm trying to reduce the dimensional of some sparse matrix X  (311 rows, 531 col) using SVD, X was normalized using L2 norm for each row before the process. Then i examine the norms of each row after the SVD. The motivation is that lower norm = less knowledge about the item, best (unrealistic) results will give me L2 norm = 1 for all items (correct me if i'm wrong please).

```
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=40,algorithm="randomized",n_iter=5)#arpack or randomized
    svd.fit(m)
    reducedMatrix = svd.transform(m)
    norm1 = np.linalg.norm(reducedMatrix, axis=1)
    print("items with small norms", [x for x in norm1 if x < 0.01])
```

I get 1 item:

> items with small norms:  1 ['0.00910137638659']

After testing this [algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061.pdf) on larger data-set i see it's much faster, but requires about double the memory (compared to the Arpack based one).

When i use the "arpack" version i get 18 values:

> items with small norms [8.6306635928619441e-17,
>   1.0277462957578221e-15, 1.4667052951818196e-15, 2.1663449662545767e-15, 1.4667052951818196e-15, 2.1663449662545767e-15, 1.173260692450235e-15, 0.0082092615042018754, 7.2954466241998462e-16, 6.9978203006252761e-16, 6.8263848770079366e-16, 1.0468700362063273e-15, 1.0468700362063273e-15, 1.2256257009844252e-15, 0.0046908528198490451, 8.6306635928619441e-17, 0.0051649957535206863, 1.1699595613141061e-15]

Here are the variance explained by each eigenvalue (note that only the first 40 are used):
[image]

This plot compares the norms (each point represents a row)
[image]

I understand that both of the algorithms are approximations. But such differnces looks troublesome - which result is more correct?

Any insights?

Comment: Thanks, but after i do this i still get 18 values (probably\almost) equal to zero on one implementation - and on the other they are higher than 0.01.

Comment: I've added a plot of the variance explained by each eigenvalue. But i think i was misunderstood, the norms are of the rows, the SVD will return all of the rows no matter what. n_iter=5 is the default.

Comment: I'm using k=40, that is why is stopped at this point. It's clear that the eigenvalues are almost equal. But the eigenvectors are not equal, thus causing the norms to be different, i just don't understand why it happens, and which result is more correct.

Comment: I've raised the value just to plot it. The blue line ends before the orange one because of a bug in Arpack implementation, the missing values are zeros.

Comment: Okay, I see now. If you use k=40 then the remaining eigenvalues do not matter, that was my confusion. Previous plot was probably more appropriate. I don't know what goes on, looks like something might be wrong in the `transform()` function. Do large values in `norm1` agree?

Comment: This second plot reveals that the difference occurs only on lower values - but not the lowest. This is very weird.

Comment: Can you check what happens with lower values of k? E.g. k=1 or k=5. Are the smaller row norms still disagreeing?

Comment: Same effect for k=5. I'm trying to compare the results to precise SVD to see which one is wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately numpy.linalg.svd uses Arpack (same implementation), and same results as truncsvd with Arpack which i used in the original post.

Comment: Why is this unfortunate? I think we can be sure beyond *any* reasonable doubt that ARPACK is correct. Not only scikit-learn uses ARPACK, it's the same library used in R, Matlab, you name it. The issue here is about randomized SVD implementation.

Comment: Did you try increasing n_iter?

Comment: As you raise this parameter, the norms are getting smaller. For the value of 20 the same norms are low but with very different values. But higher n_iter values like 100 return nonsense. This needs to be tested on other data-sets of course, i think i will use Arpack after reading your comment... Thank you.

Comment: If arpack runtime is acceptable then there is no reason not to use it. The whole idea behind randomized algorithms is to compute some approximation to the true SVD when arpack is prohibitively slow. For 300x500 matrix you should not bother.

Comment: Isn't Arpack uses some sort of approximation? I expect to use sparse matrix of size 10k*50k cells. This will require about half an hour with Arpack.

Comment: Well, ARPACK library uses Arnoldi iterations which is an iterative method (there are no non-iterative methods of computing SVD), but other than that it's not approximate. It always converges to the true solution.

Comment: Im asking because i remember that i tried to change the seed and got slightly different result. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know. What seed? There is no seed in [numpy.linalg.svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html).

Comment: I'm talking about this one: scipy.sparse.linalg.svds. I meant the v0 parameter.

Comment: Could this simply be rounding error -- different iterations, many numbers near 0 ? Try running both with np.float32 (beware, some programs silently convert inputs to float64)